# Postgresql SQL "Order By" Index Fine-Tuning Issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

We need the entire guest list (except archived guests) to show up alphabetized by last name. [Indexing on last name only helps when you need to return a small set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-ordering.html). This user has 5000+ guests in their database. It cannot be paginated since the data is pulled in order to load a autocompleted select field.

I've tested indexes on all the following situations below, and I still cannot get this SQL query to return in below 100ms. The query plan still only ever uses the basic **index_guests_on_business_id**

Am I missing something? Is there an indexing strategy that I could use for this request. It seems so simple, but it keeps taking 100+ms.

Thoughts?

index_guests_on_last_name

index_guests_on_business_id_last_name

index_guests_on_business_id_archived_last_name

```
  explain analyze
  SELECT "guests"."id", "guests"."first_name", "guests"."last_name" FROM "guests" WHERE "guests"."business_id" = 12345 AND "guests"."archived" = false ORDER BY last_name ASC
 
  EXPLAIN SHOWN BELOW

  Sort  (cost=12272.74..12284.51 rows=4710 width=26) (actual time=116.785..118.183 rows=5696 loops=1)
  Sort Key: last_name
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 654kB
     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on guests  (cost=94.80..11985.39 rows=4710 width=26) (actual time=3.336..16.203 rows=5696 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (business_id = 12345)
        Filter: (NOT archived)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
        Heap Blocks: exact=4517
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_guests_on_business_id  (cost=0.00..93.62 rows=4960 width=0) (actual time=2.092..2.092 rows=5697 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (business_id = 12345)
  Planning time: 0.162 ms
  Execution time: 118.606 ms
```

Adding a limit reduces the query to less than a millisecond.

```
explain analyze
SELECT "guests"."id", "guests"."first_name", "guests"."last_name" FROM "guests" WHERE "guests"."business_id" = 12345 AND "guests"."archived" = false ORDER BY last_name ASC LIMIT 100


Limit  (cost=0.42..317.05 rows=100 width=26) (actual time=0.034..0.339 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using index_guests_on_business_id_last_name on guests  (cost=0.42..15704.88 rows=4960 width=26) (actual time=0.032..0.312 
  rows=100 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (business_id = 12345)
Planning time: 0.321 m
Execution time: 0.567 ms
```

Is there no way to get these same improvements when returning the entire dataset, instead of just returning a small set like above (LIMIT 100)?

Comment: That sort time is egregious.  It shouldn't even take one tenth that long.  What collation are you using?  Is the server vastly overloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Try a [covering index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) to satisfy this query.

```sql
CREATE INDEX cov ON guests
   (business_id, archived, last_name)
   INCLUDE (id, first_name);
```

It should be possible to range-scan this BTREE index to satisfy your specific query without a separate sort step, and without the cost of fetching the extra columns from the heap. (Probably the latter cost is why the query planner opted for the quicksort.)

But keep in mind that a 5000-row result set takes longer to handle than a 100-row one, just because it contains more data to shove into HTML and send to a browser. Many web apps use autocomplete rather than a dropdown for fields with that many choices.